Render request for html page changes url link to #
I am using Django to render html pages. When it renders, it works fine but it changes link to #. Let me explain
views.py
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

urls.py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
....

urlpatterns = [
    path('homepage/', views.index, name='homepage'),
    path('', include(router.urls)),

]


When I want to view the html page I go to link named:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/homepage/

But when it enters the page browser link changes to :
http://127.0.0.1:8000/#/

How can I solve this issue?

Tell us what is the error you get so we can help

In your case, it seems you try to use router and REST? the code below should work. it follows the same logic, that you have include the urls of your router.
`
api_patterns = [
path('', include(router.urls)),
]
view_patterns = [
path('homepage/', views.index, name='homepage'),
]
urlpatterns = [
path('api/', include(api_patterns)),
path('', include(view_patterns)),
]
`

@MohamedElKalioby read again please. I have no error, only the html link changes.

@IsmayilIsmayilov didn't work.
